# Getting Specific PIP Package Version on Windows 11 | I have a method but is it the best?

Tags: pip, package, kivy, version

so I was able to put this together after Googling and finding some stuff around here in SOF.

I needed to see what version of kivy was currently installed on my Windows System using pip.

here is what I found:

```
pip list | FIND /I "kivy"
```

Here is the output

```
Kivy                          2.1.0
```

It did what I wanted it to do. Is there a different way that most devs get this info? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+package+version

Comment: `pip show kivy`

Comment: Hey thanks that shows even more information!
This is what I need. Thank you
@phd

`pip show kivy`

`C:\Users\TechyRican>pip show kivy`
`Name: Kivy`
`Version: 2.1.0`
`Summary: A software library for rapid development of hardware-accelerated` `multitouch applications.`
`Home-page: http://kivy.org`
`Author: Kivy Team and other contributors`
`Author-email: kivy-dev@googlegroups.com`
`License: MIT`
`Location: c:\users\techyrican\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`
`Requires: Kivy-Garden, docutils, kivy-deps.glew, kivy-deps.angle, pypiwin32` `pygments, kivy-deps.sdl2`
`Required-by:`